# Storing R projects in SharePoint

Tags: r, sharepoint

G'day

Is there a way of storing R projects in SharePoint? SharePoint doesn't like files that start with a period such as .RData and .Rhistory.

Thanks
Matt

Comment: Can you rename them to include charcters before the .?

Comment: Then I'd have to load the workspace and history manually. Not ideal, btu if there is no other solution I'll do that.